# Probability of getting an odd number of balls

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics

We have $n$ balls such that $k \ge 1$ of them are black and the rest are white. Consider the following procedure:

We first put all the balls in the bucket $B_0$. Then, we select each one of them with probability $1/2$ and put the selected ones in $B_1$. Next, we select each ball in $B_1$ with probability $1/2$ and put the selected ones in $B_2$. We continue doing that for $\Theta(\log{n})$ iterations.

What is the probability that at least one of these buckets contains an odd number of black balls?

Well, if $k$ is odd then it is easy to see that the probability is $1$, but how can we analyze this when $k$ is even?

Comment: The white balls seem to be totally irrelevant for the problem. Are you sure you got this right?

Answer (score 2):

I will use the term round $i$ to describe the move to bucket $B_i$. Note that the probability of moving even number of black balls during any round is $\frac{1}{2}$ since you can move the first $x-1$ balls randomly and then pick the last one to fix the parity. Also, note that if you have even number of balls in all $B_{k}$ up to $i$ and you move even number from $B_{i}$ to $B_{i+1}$ you are ok. That happens with probability $\frac{1}{2}^i$.

So, the final answer is $1 - \frac{1}{2}^{\Theta (\text{log}n)}$

Comment: Is $1/2^{\Theta(\log{n})}$ the probability that all the buckets contain an even number of black balls or the probability that at least one of them contains an odd number?

Comment: @arm46 You are right. I forgot to complement. I will edit. Thanks.

Comment: " the probability of moving even number of black balls during any round is $\frac12$" ... except if the bucket is empty.

Comment: @leonbloy You are right. I missed this. I silently assumed that there are only black balls since we have zero interest in the white ones. If $k = O(n)$ the result holds, I think. When $k$ is smaller, my guess is $1- \frac{1}{2}^{\Theta (\text{log} m)}$ but more work is required. Again, nice spot.

Comment: "except if the bucket is empty" Better said: "except if there are no black balls in the bucket"